# How to force Google Play Music to rescan folders in "music from this computer" section

Tags: google-play-music

I recently set up Google Play Music to add new MP3s from ~/Music on my main machine. It worked like a charm at first, but now that I've also downloaded the whole library to that folder, it doesn't recognize when new songs are added. Do I have to remove and re-add the folder to the "music from this computer" section?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Google Play Music Manager](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075570?hl=en) and turn it on (or restart it) to check the folder(s) I've added for new tracks. It does so when it starts running. I think if you left it running it would eventually check for new tracks itself, but it's quicker to restart it.